# Could some confirm my answer for this limit using taylor series?

Tags: taylor-expansion

$\lim_{x→0}$

$\dfrac{x^2}{x\sqrt{1+x} −\ln(1+x)}= ?$

I got $-2$. Is this correct if not what is the answer so i can find out where i went wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks wrong to me. How did you get it?

Comment: It is $1$, because $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+x/2$ and $\ln(1+x)\approx x-x^2/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Using Taylor series $$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ so $$x\sqrt{1+x}-\log(1+x)=x^2-\frac{11 x^3}{24}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\dfrac{x^2}{x\sqrt{1+x} −\ln(1+x)}= \frac{x^2}{x^2-\frac{11 }{24}x^3+O\left(x^4\right)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{11 }{24}x+O\left(x^2\right)}=1+\frac{11 }{24}x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Comment: Well done! (+1)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici ah i see where i went wrong, did you get 1?

Comment: @someguy. Where did you go wrong ? It could be good (for other people) to know what was your mistake. A mistake is not dramatic as long as you do not repeat it ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I wrote down the Taylor Series wrong and therefore was an error from the start.. Did you get 1 for the answer of this question?

Comment: Did you read my last expression and used $x\to 0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I did and you did get 1 I just wasnt sure what the O was thats all...

Comment: @someguy. If you have been teached Taylor series, didn't they tell you about the big $O(.)$ notation ? Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 0):

To make things look nicer and easier to do, let $y = \sqrt{1+x}$, then $L = \displaystyle \lim_{y \to 1} \dfrac{(y^2-1)^2}{y(y^2-1) - 2\ln(y)}$. From this you can apply L'hospital rule much faster than the original form.

Comment: $\ln\left(y^2\right)$ instead of $\ln\left(y\right)$ in the denominator?